# Collection Navigation in WinRT

Tags: c#, collections, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

This seems like such a trivial thing but I can’t for the life of me figure out how to do it.
I have an ObservableCollection collection which is bound to a ListView control. This all works fine and I can click to select items etc.

What I would like to do is have Navigation buttons (Next, Previous, Start etc.) which the user can click on and see the ListView update as expected.

I know that the WPF version of CollectionViewSource has stuff that makes this quite simple, but from what I can see this is missing in WinRT.

Can anybody suggest a way of achieving what I am trying to do?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have the tools to test this, but can you not follow an approach like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12872045/1416220)? When googling for WinRT CollectionViewSource limitations/problems I only see reference to ICollectionView lacking sorting & filtering in WinRT apps. Sorry if I'm mistaken.

Comment: What would you like the buttons to do? Update selection states to previous values?

Comment: Simon - that implementation works. I'm positive I tried that before but following that post it's all working fine. Thank you!

Comment: Simon, should have posted an answer and got the rep ;)

Comment: @lookitskris, I'd be interested to see the code for this actually if you don't mind posting the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @GONeale I can't test WinRT code and I'm actually unsure if my answer from the other question that I linked would make this question a dupe :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've found out about CollectionViewSource in XAML WinRT I only see reference to ICollectionView lacking sorting & filtering in WinRT apps. So a WPF approach will work such as the one suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12872045/1416220).